# How to create synchronized web GUIs?

Tags: java, web, synchronization

I am wondering how can I create synchronized web GUIs.

I ask this because I would like to see my web application GUI synchronized on all of my clients. How can this be achieved?

I'm not sure what to search on the Internet regarding this issue...

Comment: What do you mean by "synchronized"? What does it have to do with Java? How do web sockets/similar not solve the problem?

Comment: My application is a web application written in Java and runs on a Tomcat server. What I am trying to say is that when a user makes a change in the GUI, the other users should see the change immediately, without refreshing the page or without making Ajax calls. I've never user sockets

Comment: Good time to start. If you refuse to use Ajax, it's your only real option, although note that web socket compatibility libs use Ajax to simulate it.

Comment: "Without refreshing the page or without making Ajax calls" [sic] -- I don't know that this is possible.  Unlike a screen on a desktop application, a web page does not have a connection to the web page server with which it can have updates pushed to it, without Ajax or something similar.  Even if you used Ajax, I would examine what you meant by "immediately" before I told you it would work; web applications are often expected to scale up to tens or hundreds of thousands of users, or more; it is hard to know whether things would be "immediate" enough without knowing more about what you want.

Comment: Tomcat Websockets are the only answer.